# Good patterns for rounding UIViews?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

With the recent updates of XCode 8, Swift 3 and iOS10 my old pattern for rounding UIViews became obsolete. What I used to do was:

```
@IBOutlet weak var pointsView: UIView! {
    didSet {
        pointsView.setRound()
    }
}
```

Where setRound is defined as an extension:

```
extension UIView {
    func setRound() {
        self.layer.cornerRadius = self.bounds.width / 2
    }
}
```

Now I cannot use this pattern anymore as the outlets get set before they have correct bounds. So in almost every case bounds.width / 2 is greater than the real bounds.width and the views disappear.

I really enjoyed this style as the rounding was defined where the UIView was set and all the other layer based styling was done too.

So now I'm asking you what is your way to do rounding? Why do you do it in your way?

Comment: you can add an attribute in identity inspector under 'User Defined Runtime Attributes'. Set key path to "layer.cornerRadius" and set its value to your desired corner.

Comment: I don't want to define it there as I'd have to change the value every time I change the view size.

Answer (score 1):

call `setRound` function from `viewDidLayoutSubviews` or after layout have done inshort. Or you should take outlet of your `width constraint` of your view and set corner radius as half of `constant` of constrain's outlet!

Comment: What I'm doing now (as a band-aid) is that I call the function in viewDidAppear, which I guess is the same as viewDidLayoutSubviews. With constraint it could work, but then again there would be a lot of extra code and hassle to change the logic.

Comment: Actually it seems like that viewDidLayoutSubviews works a lot better than viewDidAppear. Thanks for that! But still need to figure out a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: yeah `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is better than `viewDidAppear`!!